# android detect change connection dont work

Tags: android

I'm wondering why this simple `receiver` for detecting connection change don't work for me, it is like with al other sample which i search on google

in this sample application i have only one activity and broadcast

`BroadcastReceiver`:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public ConnectivityReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Log.e("onReceive ", " ,  ");
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.sample.sampleapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

after turning on/off i dont have any output on logcat

and its my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you targeting this for android N+?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is targeting **Android N**, then you must have to register your **CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE** broadcast dynamically **Context.registerReceiver()**.

**Reference:** 
[Android N Background Optimizations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#bg-opt)

Comment: This has been there since Nougat and the proper link is https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#bg-opt

Comment: @humblerookie - Thanks for the correction, answer is updated :)

Comment: @MohitCharadva you have right, i'm sorry, after change `targetSdkVersion` to 23 problem resolved, how can i register `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` now?

Comment: @humblerookie how can i register CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy create a broadcastreceiver in your application class and register it there with the intentfilter containing `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE `